# Approximating Random MAX-k-SAT

Tags: ds.algorithms, sat, approximation-hardness, pcp, random-k-sat

It is known [[de la Vega & Karpinski 2002](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.6.3836)] that random instances of MAX-3-SAT on $n$ variables can be approximated up to fraction at least 8/9 w.h.p. tending to 1 as $n$ tends to infinity.

Should one expect this to be close to optimal?
In fact, is it possible, that random MAX-k-SAT instances can be approximated within any desirable fraction w.h.p.?
At least on the face of it - this should not contradict the PCP theorem, whose output SAT instances are very construction-specific (Dinur) and are thus sets with negligible probability in this respect.

Comment: What do you mean by "approximate 3-SAT"?  Do you mean "approximate MAX-3-SAT"?

Comment: “[Fernandez et. al]” is a very poor way of citing a paper.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito I think the full citation is [9/8-Approximation Algorithm for Random MAX-3SAT (2002) by W. Fernandez de la Vega, Marek Karpinski](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.6.3836), which also confirms my previous comment (that we are talking about MAX-3-SAT, not 3-SAT).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Their result is not optimal. First, it was improved upon by Yannet Interian. She obtained a 20/19 approximation (if I recall correctly). See the reference:

> Y. Interian. Approximation algorithm for Random MAX-kSAT. Theory and Applications of Satisfiability Testing (SAT 2004), Revised Selected Papers. LNCS 3542, 2005.

Her result has apparently been improved further by [Fernandez de la Vega and Karpinski](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=8224129) to 1.0957, but I cannot find an online preprint of this paper.

Given such a low approximation ratio, I wonder if it is reasonable to conjecture that there is a PTAS.

Comment: Isn't 20/19 better than 1.0957 ?

Comment: There is an older version [here](http://theory.cs.uni-bonn.de/ftp/reports/cs-reports/2003/85247-CS.ps.gz).

Comment: Ha, thanks! I mistakenly assumed that since one result was published after the other one, clearly the latter bound must be better...

Comment: @Lior, you can accept Ryan's answer by clicking on the check mark on his answer.